# Maven can't find package but package is there

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, jar

My Spring Boot project contains four modules: one wrapper and three modules inside of it. The structure is this:

- Module: *synergpt-wrapper*

  - Sub-module: *api*
  - Sub-module: *concrete*
  - Sub-module: *core*

Here's the pom.xml for synergpt-wrapper:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>iet.synergpt</groupId>
    <artifactId>synergpt-wrapper</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>synergpt-wrapper-test-automation</name>
    <description>SynerGPT Wrapper for Test Automation</description>
    <modules>
        <module>api</module>
        <module>concrete</module>
        <module>core</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.1.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <appium.client.version>8.3.0</appium.client.version>

    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

then for api:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <name>api</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>iet.synergpt</groupId>
        <artifactId>synergpt-wrapper</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <appium.client.version>8.3.0</appium.client.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.1.Final</mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--WEBSOCKET DEPS-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cedarsoftware</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.68.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>${appium.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.browserup</groupId>
            <artifactId>browserup-proxy-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>iet.synergpt</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

then for core:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <name>core</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>iet.synergpt</groupId>
        <artifactId>synergpt-wrapper</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-service-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.11.0</version>
               <configuration>
                   <source>17</source>
                   <target>17</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and finally for concrete

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>iet.synergpt</groupId>
        <artifactId>synergpt-wrapper</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>concrete</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>synergpt-test-automation</name>
    <description>SynerGPT Test Automation</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.1.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <appium.client.version>8.3.0</appium.client.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>${appium.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-edge-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.browserup</groupId>
            <artifactId>browserup-proxy-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>iet.synergpt</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

(I removed URLs from the pom files, as StackOverflow flagged those as spam)

For some reason, the project won't build (I use `mvn clean install package`, because i need to build an executable jar of API). The core package builds correctly, and i can find it inside my local .m2 repo. But when it comes to building api (which has a dependency on core) Maven acts like the core package does not exist. It simply points to the first occurrence of an import `iet.synergpt.core.**something**` inside some class of the api package, and just spits out `cannot find package iet.synergpt.core.something`. As you can see in the POM, api depends on core, but that should not be a problem.

The strangest thing is that IntelliJ actually runs everything correctly: i can simply press play on the SpringBootApplication class and everything is parsed and runs properly. The problem seems to reside in Maven.
I have already tried everything: deleting the .m2, cloning the project from scratch, invalidating caches in IntelliJ, but nothing happens.

Can you help me out here?

Comment: Concrete error messages are good and useful. Also, *show*, rather than tell us that the Maven artifact with the package is there.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the Run Config that IDEA creates and the exact error that Maven returns? I'm assuming you are running Maven for the parent Project (synergpt-wrapper)? Not sure why you had to explicitly specify the api's core dependency scope?